# Make object Object as index of array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I've been using a crossword app from this repo: https://github.com/jweisbeck/Crossword . The problem is that the program uses jquery version 1.6.2 and my whole project uses jquery-3.1.1 version. Particularly, the error arises here:

```
buildEntries: function() {
    var puzzCells = $('#puzzle td'),
        light,
        $groupedLights,
        hasOffset = false,
        positionOffset = entryCount - puzz.data[puzz.data.length-1].position; // diff. between total ENTRIES and highest POSITIONS

    for (var x=1, p = entryCount; x <= p; ++x) {
        var letters = puzz.data[x-1].answer.split('');

        for (var i=0; i < entries[x-1].length; ++i) {

            light = $(puzzCells +'[data-coords="' + entries[x-1][i] + '"]');

            if($(light).empty()){
                console.log($(light));
                $(light)
                    .addClass('entry-' + (x-1) + ' position-' + (x-1) )
                    .append('<input maxlength="1" val="" type="text" tabindex="-1" />');
            }
        }
    }

    // Put entry number in first 'light' of each entry, skipping it if already present
    console.log(entries);
    console.log(puzz.data);
    for (var i = 0; i < entryCount; i++) {
        $groupedLights = $('.entry-' + i); 
        if(!$('.entry-' + i +':eq(0) span').length){
            $groupedLights.eq(0)
                .append('<span>' + puzz.data[i].position + '</span>');
        }
    }

    util.highlightEntry();
    util.highlightClue();
    $('.active').eq(0).focus();
    $('.active').eq(0).select();            
}
```

The error arises at line with

```
light = $(puzzCells +'[data-coords="' + entries[x-1][i] + '"]');
```

The browser shows this error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression [object Object][data-coords="1,6"]

I believe this is related to the jQuery version. Or maybe the program uses [object Object] as index. Not sure as I am new in jQuery. I tried to use jQuery Migrate, but it didn't help. Also, I tried to use that jQuery 1.6.2, but a web browser could not find jQuery at all as I am using Typescript and had to install jQuery through .d.ts file. Any tips or advises? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `[object Object]` in the string shown in the error is because a jQuery object is being appended to a string to create a selector, which is invalid.

In your code, it's this line causing the problem:

```
var puzzCells = $('#puzzle td') // holds jQuery object

// later on...
light = $(puzzCells + '[data-coords="' + entries[x-1][i] + '"]');
```

This is nothing to do with the version of jQuery being used as it's a syntax issue.

To fix this you should use `filter()` on the `puzzCells` object, instead of appending it to a selector. Try this:

```
light = puzzCells.filter('[data-coords="' + entries[x-1][i] + '"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

As the title says:

> Make object Object as index of array

That is not possible with standard Objects/Arrays, but you can use a Map for that:

```
let map = new Map(),
    key = {id: '##'};

map.set(key, [1,2,3,4,5]);

console.log(map.get(key)); //[1,2,3,4,5]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: I don't see how this is relevant to what's being asked?

Comment: Firstly the title makes no sense. Secondly if you read the question this is completely irrelevant to the actual problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah, in the description I stated that maybe the problem is not related to [object Object] being index of array aka the title. But thanks for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating an object (`puzzCells`) and a string. When JavaScript detects an string concatenation tries to convert all the variables to strings before concatenating them. In plain JavaScript, if you do `WHATEVEROBJECT.toString()` you will receive `[object Object]`, that's why you see an error containing that message.

This is not jQuery version problem, as this happens at the very low level (JavaScript).

`puzzCells` is a jQuery object, where you can call jQuery methods. In this case you need the filter method, like this:

```
light = puzzCells.filter('[data-coords="' + entries[x-1][i] + '"]');
```

Check out more info right here: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! Knew all that stuff with strings concatenation, but still doesn't understand why the same code works with jquery-1.6.2 version and doesn't with other jQuery versions.

Comment: @AkhmediyarSailaubekov Because `[object Object][whatever]` is a valid selector in jQuery 1.6.2, but actually don't selects nothing. The length of the selector will be zero. Newer versions have better syntax checks, to avoid problems like this (thinking that is selecting something, but actually doesn't).